# "Nobody knows anything yet" questions

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few questions (most recently "[Is Xcode a requirement or can I use AppCode for development in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010143/is-xcode-a-requirement-or-can-i-use-appcode-for-development-in-swift)") of the form "Some company just made some big announcement and there's very little information available, can anyone tell me more?"

It seems like questions of this form are unlikely to produce good answers, since nobody has much more information than the OP. I voted to close this one as "Off-Topic / Recommend or find a tool", but I'm not sure that's the best response. Thoughts?

Comment: *Don't abuse the close reasons!*  The OP wasn't asking for a product recommendation.

Comment: "Can I use A or do I have to use B" seems like borderline asking for a recommendation. Though "primarily opinion-based" will probably be more accurate within 24 hours or so since JetBrains has announced they're adding minimal syntax highlighting support as soon as they can, and then it the question effectively morphs into "Is AppCode Swift support good enough to use yet"?

Comment: It should be said that a lot more is known about this than is typical for new product announcements from Apple, given that the full documentation for the language is available: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-XID_0 and Apple's finally relaxed the NDA around the stuff being discussed at WWDC. However, animuson is right here, in that this question is one about planned features for a third party's future product. Only Jetbrains could answer that.

Comment: I don't see that it's valid to close just because no-one knows yet. At some point someone will know, and then the question will get a good answer.

Comment: @superluminary I'm not sure the question would ever get a good answer. At best (once AppCode does have Swift support) I expect it would devolve into an opinion-based "is AppCode or XCode better for Swift development?"

Comment: related: [Is it okay to close questions about preview and beta products](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106265/183280)

Comment: @DavidMoles The best answer will change over time, but isn't that the case for many questions on the site. It's a relatively closed question, not an open tool recommendation.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general product support which can only be answered by the development team.

Problem solved.

Stack Overflow is not a substitution for a support forum, which is exactly where this question belongs. It's basically a direct question to the AppCode team asking them if they will support Swift in the future. We can't know, only they can, and therefore it does not belong here. Custom reasons are the best for this.

I imagine most would fall under the "general product support" category, but it's too hard to generalize an entire "nobody knows anything yet" category with a solid answer. It's a very case-by-case basis, but ultimately "lack of information" *alone* is not a valid reason to close something. If it's close-worthy there's always a better reason than that.

Comment: What about the more general question?  "Nobody knows anything yet"

Comment: @RobertHarvey: "*This question appears to be off-topic because it asks about the future, and [StackOverflow is not a crystal ball](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not)*" :-)

Answer (score 6):

It's a valid question for SO.  It probably won't get an answer right away but that doesn't make it any less valid.

Comment: Is it, though? It's already easy to answer with a quick Google.

Comment: It being on google doesn't make it an invalid question.

Comment: This answer is correct, however this specific post in question *isn't* a valid question on SO.  If it were in fact a valid question, and nobody knew the answer, then that lack of an answer isn't reason to close it.

Comment: @MxyL well, yes and no.  There's a question on meta.SE, [What should one do if they have a question that the answer is already on google?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208372), where the consensus seems to be that "if Google finds the answer in the documentation for you, it doesn't need to be a Stack Overflow question."  After all (and as I commented there), "The standard documentation is someplace that a 'professional or enthusiast programmer' should have looked before coming to Stack Overflow. People needing such an answer should have found it before they got to Stack Overflow."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I agree, for example if the question was trivial enough to the point where you could literally just copy paste text from the docs. And many times I do find myself seeing a question about some tool/library, going to the docs, and seeing a line that seems to answer the question. But even when it's right there in the docs, sometimes this information is not obvious to find and requires some digging around, in which case if I had to spend 5 minutes looking for it, maybe I can save someone else 5 minutes of their time.

Comment: I agree with @MxyL that if it was trivial to find under Google it doesn't belong on SO but if not, then it does have a place. For something like Android+Phonegap in particular, I find the documentation to be fairly average unless you know 100% what you are looking for. For something like Javascript, MDM has extensive documentation and is really straight forward all while generally being in the first few results. I think it really needs to be looked at on a question-by-question basis.

Comment: On the other hand @JoshuaTaylor, here is another thread on meta suggesting something else: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions/8743#8743

Comment: @Alex I agree, it's not clear cut. Plenty of times, the user doesn't know the terms that would help them get to the right part of the documentation.  "Copy the documentation" results are useful then.  Also, the post I linked to is more recent, from 2013; the one you linked is from 2008, and standards have changed somewhat over time.  I posted my comment mostly because there was a comment "It being on google doesn't make it an invalid question." and a post titled "What should one do if they have a question that the answer is already on google?" and it seemed like a good pairing.

Comment: Aside from documentation, the same google remark is used when someone entered a query and was led to a blog or 3rd party site that shared a solution. In particular, for questions that can't be filled with copy-paste jobs from docs, it is almost always a link to a 3rd party site. It could be a reputable site/person, or it might not. I've been directed to RoseIndia a couple times, and while I guess it could be a reputable site, l but wasn't really satisfied with the solutions then.